# Choice options in Angular MultipleSelect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I'm new in AngularJS, I'm used angularMultipleSelect library. I've a list with different options but when a user chooses a option the next select must filter only the children of that options but all the options must show in the main list. Example, "Image et home cinéma" and "Audio et hifi" are a child of "Multimedia (Brun)" but this three option it's in the main list.

This is my data

```
    $scope.typeBien = 
      [
        {"name": "Multimedia (Brun)"},
        {"name": "Image et home cinéma"},
        {"name": "Audio et hifi"},
        {"name": "Sani broyeur"},
        {"name": "Vid%uFFFDophone"},
        {"name": "Amplificateur %uFFFDlectrique (ampli d'antenne)"},
        {"name": "Antenne et parabole (motorisation)"},
        {"name": "Aspirateur centralis%uFFFD"},
        {"name": "Ascenseur (parties %uFFFDlectriques)"},
        {"name": "Cl%uFFFDture %uFFFDlectrique"},
        {"name": "Domotique"},
        {"name":"Aspirateurs"},
        {"name":"Coiffure"},
        {"name":"Centrale vapeur"},
        {"name":"Fer à repasser"},
        {"name":"Sèche cheveux"},
        {"name":"Fer à lisser"},
        {"name":"Fer à boucler"},
        {"name":"Tondeuses coiffure"},
        {"name": "Interphone"},
        {"name": "Monte escalier (partie %uFFFDlectrique)"}
    ];
```

this is my function but no filter after selected the option.

```
    $scope.selectItemCallback = function(item){
          $scope.selectedItem = item;

     if (item.name == "Multimedia (Brun)"){
      $scope.typeBien = $scope.multimedia;
    }

          if (item.name == "Image et home cinéma"){
            $scope.typeBien = $scope.multimedia_1;
          }

          if (item.name == "Audio et hifi"){
            $scope.typeBien = $scope.multimedia_2;
          }
      };
```

any help I would be grateful

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Can you create a jsfiddle or plunker to show what you have done?

Comment: Hello, I could fix the question, but I can not publish in plunker because the code is part of a larger application, thanks for the help.